What screws should be used to mount and secure a "floating" closet to the wall?
I moved into an apartment that has a closet as shown in the picture. The outside side panels are attached to a rail perpendicularly. So, the entire closet doesn't reach the floor. I want to raise it a few inches and also attach the side panels to the studs if possible or to the drywall. What screws should I use to attach the rail and side panels to the studs and what screws to attach them to the drywall? The attached picture shows the screws I saw at the home depot. It looks like drywall screws is a bad choice because they only attach the drywall to the studs but aren't strong enough to support the weight and might break, right? What about others, are there any that might work? Or which ones do you recommend I use?


Hi, welcome to Woodworking! "...but aren't strong enough to support the weight and might break, right?" That's the conventional wisdom/prevailing belief among woodworkers but the facts speak for themselves that actually they can indeed be much more suitable than was previously thought. They are however shorter than you want for this application so you can neatly sidestep that controversy. Although there are other screws that will absolutely work here (based on my experience + viewing tests conducted by various YTers) you might as well skip all the way to construction screws for zero worries.

Assuming this belief is true, why not use wood screws and use a construction screw instead? As far as I understand, a construction screw is much stronger. But isn't a construction screw overkill in this case? Also, what type of construction screw do you recommend, #8 or thicket like #10? And what length, 2'' or 3'' in my case?

You should always assume that there is an electrical cable or plumbing passing through the stud you are screwing into. You are safe if you don't penetrate the stud by more than 1.25". If you are drilling a pilot hole, be careful to not drill beyond this depth. To determine the max screw length, take the 1.25" plus the drywall thickness (e.g., 0.5") plus the thickness of the item you are screwing to the wall minus the depth of any countersinking of the screw head. Longer is not always better. If you find a metal plate under the drywall, that indicates that there is wiring <1.25" in the stud.

1/4" x 2.5" is the size you want. Ideally you'd go with wood screws, but the sheet metal screws will work just fine if that's all you can get. (The brand you have pictured may not be the best quality available.) Since this is a rental, you might want to set this shelf unit on some kind of "feet" instead of putting screws into the wall, etc.

"....why not .... use a construction screw instead? As far as I understand, a construction screw is much stronger" That's exactly what I advised. It is indeed overkill (screws way below this in the food chain are perfectly sufficient, even without going into studs (used with appropriate plugs). But like I say if you want to have zero worries, irrespective of how much weight this will ever be loaded with.
